# Legend with transparent frame and non-transparent edge

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, alpha

When setting the transparency in a legend:

```
plt.legend(framealpha=0.5)
```

it affects both the background and the edge. How can I apply transparency only to the background and not to the edge?

I have tried:

```
plt.legend(edgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1.), facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0.1))
```

with which I can change the color but not the transparency, i.e., using `facecolor=(1, 0, 0, 0.1)` does change the background color to red but using `facecolor=(1, 0, 0, 0.5)` doesn't make any difference in transparency.

I'm using matplotlib v3.1.1.

Comment: `plt.legend(edgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1.), facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0.1))` works fine for me. Can you give more information about the problem you face?

Comment: Interesting. There is no difference in using `facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0.1)` and `facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0.9)` for me. I'm using matplotlib v3.1.1.

Comment: I see; ***that*** would be the real question then.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `framealpha` overrides the alpha value of the actual edge- or facecolors. Hence one would need to set the color, including alpha, manually on the legend patch.

```
legend = plt.legend(loc="upper right", edgecolor="black")
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(None)
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor((0, 0, 1, 0.1))
```